# How the parameter passed in IIFE works

Tags: javascript, iife

Just looking throug some js code file that has all it's code wrapped like that:

```
(function(self) {

//..

})(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this);
```

Can you explain what is the javascript code above means:

What is `self` and where it is coming from?

What is the last line is actually does `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this);` ?

Comment: This is an **Immediatly Invoked Function**.

Comment: `self` is a global variable in *browsers* that refers to the global object. This just checks if that variable exists. If yes, it is passed to the function. If not, `this` is passed, which in the global scope would also refer to the global object.

Comment: @FelixKling the second `self` because the first one is just an argument.

Comment: **Immediately Invoked Function *Expression*** or **IIFE**

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Sure, I'm just talking about the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(self);

console.log(this);
```

```
(function(){

})();
```

this is the syntax for `IIFE` in javascript (Immediatelyinvoked function expression).

Now ..

```
 (function(x){

    })(y);
```

now first `()` contains the actual anonymous function , and second `()` is used to call that function. WHat you pass in second get received by first.

So,

```
(function(self) {

//..

})(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this);
```

`typeof self !== 'undefined'` will check if `self` (Browser global object) is existing or not. If its existing its passed otherwise `this` the scope of the object or global scope is passed.

`self` and `this` will provide same object here at root.